# python beautifulsoup no data retreived between div tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get data using Beautifulsoup on this website "http://www.jps.go.cr/" however when I get the data all the information between the tags is missing. I can confirm that the data is there inspecting the website however once I run the code it does not show.

here is the code:------------

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="http://www.jps.go.cr/productos/loteria-nacional"
req = Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"detail_ultimoSorteo loteria"})
print(all)
```

I would appreciate any help since I am driving crazy, other websites work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a case of a slow loaded page that requires a method like selenium to leave time for content to be loaded fully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is slow loading and needs a method such as selenium which allow enough time for your content to become available.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'http://www.jps.go.cr/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.detail_ultimoSorteo.loteria').text)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr. As for the css used I found 2 and I didn't get the output but when used this line `print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='detail col-sm-12']").text)` this worked for me ..

Answer (score 1):

You can get the required content in a slightly different manner. There is a library ***[pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer)*** which can handle dynamic content very efficiently. Check out the following implementation:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def fetch_items():
    wb = await launch()
    page = await wb.newPage()
    await page.goto("http://www.jps.go.cr/")

    container = await page.querySelector('.detail_ultimoSorteo')
    items = await page.evaluate('(element) => element.innerText', container)
    print(items.strip())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(fetch_items())
```

Result:

```
Sorteo 4520
Domingo, 2 de Diciembre 2018
Primer premio

61 366 ₡ 120.000.000
Segundo premio

60 879 ₡ 18.000.000
Tercer premio

92 401 ₡ 8.000.000
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in your case just posting for you (I know PhantomJS has been deprecated you can use Chrome drivers).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url="http://www.jps.go.cr/productos/loteria-nacional"

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"detail_ultimoSorteo"})
print(all)
```

out put

[image]